# What is wrong with my GCD algorithm?

Tags: c

Here is my attempt at computing the GCD of two input numbers:

```
int rep;
do{
    system ("cls");
    int a, b, gcd=2, e, d;
    cin >> a >> b;
    if(a % b != 0 || b % a != 0){
        do{
            gcd = gcd + 1;
            d = a % gcd;
            e = b % gcd;        
        } while(d==0 && e==0);
        cout << gcd-1;
    }else if(a == 1 || b == 1){
        gcd=1;
        cout << gcd;
    }else if(a >= b){
        gcd = a;
        cout << gcd;
    }else if(b >= a){
        gcd = b;
        cout << gcd;
    }
    cin >> rep;
} while(rep == 1);
```

If I input 8 and 24, it gives me 2 as the answer. Can anyone spot the problem in my code?

Comment: in one word: Everything

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the algorithm gives up the first time a test GCD fails.  In most cases, finding the **greatest** means going past some values that do not work.  In this case, working up to 8 means getting past 3, 5 and 7.

8 % 24 == 8.  So the `do` loop runs at least once.  `gcd` becomes 3 and is tested, but does not divide evenly into 8, so the `while` condition evaluates to false.  Then `3 - 1` (2) is streamed to `cout`.  It's not the correct GCD, though.

You could revise your algorithm to start with the lesser of the 2 inputs, and work downward until there is a success (8 here), and then a failure (7 here).

Answer (score 0):

The meat of the GCD algorithm here is only 3 lines, the rest is devoted to preventing silliness.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned GCD(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned z;
    if (x < y) {
        z = x;                  // swap
        x = y;
        y = z;
    }
    if (y == 0)
        return 0;
    while (z = x % y) {         // perform the GCD with implicit 0 test
        x = y;
        y = z;
    }
    return y;
}

int main(void)
{
    printf("GCD of %u, %u = %u\n", 1, 0, GCD(1, 0));    // billed as C
    printf("GCD of %u, %u = %u\n", 0, 1, GCD(0, 1));
    printf("GCD of %u, %u = %u\n", 1, 1, GCD(1, 1));
    printf("GCD of %u, %u = %u\n", 8, 24, GCD(8, 24));
    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
GCD of 1, 0 = 0
GCD of 0, 1 = 0
GCD of 1, 1 = 1
GCD of 8, 24 = 8
```